# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/huawei/hms/ads/identifier/AdvertisingIdClient;

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

Error message is below. I'm waiting for your help

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/huawei/hms/ads/identifier/AdvertisingIdClient;
at com.useinsider.insider.j0$f.run(Unknown Source:33)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:929)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.huawei.hms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app//base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/==/lib/arm64, /data/app//base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /hw_product/lib64, /system/product/lib64]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:209)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
at com.useinsider.insider.j0$f.run(Unknown Source:33) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:929)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Please check whether you add `maven { url 'https://developer.huawei.com/repo/' }` to the gradle file in the project directory.
2. Please ensure that the gradle file in the app directory inherits the SDK `implementation 'com.huawei.hms:ads-identifier:3.4.34.301'`

For more details, please refer to docs [here](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides-V5/identifier-service-integrating-sdk-0000001056460552-V5?ha_source=hms1).